# Docker for Mac: Using Persistent Storage

Tags: docker, macos-sierra, persistent-storage

I have recently discovered Docker for Mac (version 1.13.1). I am trying to work out how to use persistent storage.

What is the correct syntax for creating and using persistent storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you read [Manage data in containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/).

One option is to mount a host directory:

```
docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

This would mount the directory `/src/webapp` located on your host to directory `/webapp` in the container.

Comment: Got it: `-v local-folder:docker-folder`. Interesting that the article you referenced also includes creating a data volume container which seems to be a more enduring solution. Thanks